# DbContext Depedency Injection Issue - System.ObjectDisposedException: Cannot access a disposed object

Tags: asp.net, .net, entity-framework, asp.net-core-mvc

I have written my first .Net core program using the MVC framework on a Ubuntu machine. In the program I am trying to interact with SQLite database. The database CRUD operations work fine when processed through the controller class. However when I tried to operate on the database outside the controller I get following error

"*Unhandled Exception: **System.ObjectDisposedException:** **Cannot access a disposed object**. A common cause of this error is disposing a context that was resolved from dependency injection and then later trying to use the same context instance elsewhere in your application. This may occur if you are calling Dispose() on the context, or wrapping the context in a using statement. If you are using dependency injection, you should let the dependency injection container take care of disposing context instances.
**Object name:** '**MyDbContext**'.*"

For operation outside the controller class, I created a class named **MyDbWatch.cs** (in the project root director)

```
    public interface IMyDbWatch { }

    public class MyDbWatch : IMyDbWatch
    {  
        private readonly MyDbContext _dbContext; 
        private static Timer _timer;
        private AutoResetEvent _autoEvent = null;

        public MyDbWatch(MyDbContext context)
        {
            _dbContext = context;   

            _autoEvent = new AutoResetEvent(false);
            _timer = new Timer(
                callback: async s => await OnTimerEventAsync(s),
                state: _autoEvent,
                dueTime: 5000,  
                period: 10000);              
        }    

        public async Task OnTimerEventAsync(Object stateInfo)    
        {    
            Console.WriteLine("retreiving from db - 1");
            var ienStates = from m in _dbContext.IenState select m;  
            Console.WriteLine("retreiving from db - 2");         
            var listdb = await ienStates.ToListAsync();
            Console.WriteLine("retreiving from db - 3");                             
        } 
    }
```

Here how I inject different dependencies in **Startup.cs** file

```
public class Startup
{
    private MyDbWatch _myDbWatch;

    public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        Configuration = configuration;
    }

    public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.Configure<CookiePolicyOptions>(options =>
        {                
            options.CheckConsentNeeded = context => true;
            options.MinimumSameSitePolicy = SameSiteMode.None;
        });            

        services.AddDbContext<IpointWebMcmContext>(options =>
            options.UseSqlite(Configuration.GetConnectionString("IpointContext")));           

        services.AddScoped<IMyDbWatch, MyDbWatch>(); 

        services.AddMvc().SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_2);
    }

    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, 
    IMyDbWatch dbwatch)
    {
        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        }
        else
        {
            app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");                
            app.UseHsts();
        }

        _myDbWatch = dbwatch;           

        app.UseHttpsRedirection();
        app.UseStaticFiles();
        app.UseCookiePolicy();           

        app.UseMvc(routes =>
        {
            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "default",
                template: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
        });
    }
}
```

The the timer callback function **OnTimerEventAsync** in **MyDbWatch.cs** gets called first time and debug text 'retreiving from db - 1' get printed in the console. And after that I get the error

**Unhandled Exception: System.ObjectDisposedException: Cannot access a disposed object...**.

Any help resolve this issue would be highly appreciated. I need this kind of watch on the database to push data to the client through the use of SignalR hub framework (not included in the code yet).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

And this would be why statics should be avoided. Virtually every time you have a static like this, some developer is going to trip over it, because they aren't considering how things actually work.

The `static` keyword isn't magic. You've got a scoped service where you want to persist state (your timer), so you just slap a `static` on it and call it a day. However, this service uses other scoped services (your context), which now are out of sync with this static timer, i.e. the timer sticks around, but the context doesn't.

First, if you need to maintain state across an application lifetime, you should be using a singleton scope. That frees you from the terror of `static`. However, then, you'll need to utilize the server-locator pattern to get your context, because you cannot inject a scoped instance into a singleton.

```
public class MyDbWatch : IMyDbWatch
{  
    private readonly IServiceProvider _serviceProvider; 
    private readonly Timer _timer;
    private AutoResetEvent _autoEvent = null;

    public MyDbWatch(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
    {
        _serviceProvider = serviceProvider;

        _autoEvent = new AutoResetEvent(false);
        _timer = new Timer(
            callback: async s => await OnTimerEventAsync(s),
            state: _autoEvent,
            dueTime: 5000,  
            period: 10000);              
    }    

    public async Task OnTimerEventAsync(Object stateInfo)    
    {    
        using (var scope = _serviceProvider.CreateScope())
        {
            var context = scope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<MyDbContext>();

            Console.WriteLine("retreiving from db - 1");
            var ienStates = from m in context.IenState select m;  
            Console.WriteLine("retreiving from db - 2");         
            var listdb = await ienStates.ToListAsync();
            Console.WriteLine("retreiving from db - 3");                             
         }
     } 
}
```

Then, in `ConfigureServices`:

```
services.AddSingleton<IMyDbWatch, MyDbWatch>();
```

Now, I have no idea what you're actually trying to accomplish with any of this, as your code doesn't make much sense, but the above is the only way you're going to safely be able to do it.

Comment: Thanks, you resolved the issue. I am doing what I am doing for learning purpose. I want to periodically push data to the client using a SignalR Core Hub.  Building on your answer, I get an instance of the hub `var hubContext = scope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<IHubContext<MyHub>>();`  and then send message  `await hubContext.Clients.All.SendAsync("DbStateMsg", listdb);`. All this works. But I have issue in parsing the msgs in JavaScript hub client.

Comment: @Jatala I would suggest you accept the solutiona as answer to close this thread, and open a new issue .